# Technique to convert database to sql script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to convert a database into an sql script
so that i can recreate it elsewhere. I want the copy to be same as original.

How do i do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate DB Script using Management Studio through available option.

```
Right Click on Database -> Task -> Generate Scripts
```

[image]

[Here is an option for including Data with Schema in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txpwz.png)

Comment: The database is copied, but with some errors. I am ignoring the errors for now. 

Main thing is There are no rows in any of the tables !!! How do i get the rows also in my script, ie insert into....?

Comment: There is an option 'Advanced' on Set Scripting option screen. Click on that and check `Type of Data to script`, select its value to `Schema and Data`. then it will also include the data.

Comment: Also, if you want to simply get the exact same database somewhere else, you may want to do a backup to disk, copy the file, and restore it on the other server. This way it will take with it everything (data schema, etc.)

Comment: @Sachin - Type of Data to script option is not present. Probably, disabled by admin???

Comment: @Arsen - tried that. but db is on remote server. I can rdp into remote server, but cant copy paste backup into local. I was hoping to copy to local and then upload that copy to another server. Well i guess thats not gonna happen.

Comment: Answer accepted. Probably not working for me because of permission problems. But might work for some one else who has a simpler use case.

Comment: @Etl Dude - can you copy the backup to a network share location that is accessible from the remote server? Then you can restore it from the network share. backup database [XYZ] to disk = '\\server1\networkshare\XYZ_yyyyMMddhh.bak' with init

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Management Studio, right click on the database, select Tasks->Generate Scripts. It will guide you through a wizard.

Comment: The database is copied, but with some errors. I am ignoring the errors for now. 

Main thing is There are no rows in any of the tables !!! How do i get the rows also in my script, ie insert into....?